# How to add nodes to a single linked list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have started learning about algorithms in C#. I have been trying to create a linked list algorithm by myself (just for fun). I am having one issue however. I am wondering, how can I add nodes to the list? Right now I have three methods that interact with the nodes, but the list is empty so nothing happens.

**Node Class**

```
class Node {
    public int info;
    public Node link;

    public Node (int i)
    {
        info = i;
        link = null;
    }
}
```

**SingleLinkedList Class**

```
class SingleLinkedList {
    private Node start;

    public SingleLinkedList ()
    {
        start = null;
    }

    public void CreateList() {
        //TODO: Create the linked list here
    }

    public void DisplayList() {
        Node p;
        if (start == null) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Your list is empty, idiot");
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("List is :  ");
        p = start;
        while (p != null) {
            Console.WriteLine (p.info + " ");
            p = p.link;
        }
        Console.WriteLine ();
    }

    public void CountNodes() {
        int n = 0;
        Node p = start;
        while (p != null) {
            n++;
            p = p.link;
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("Number of nodes in list is = " + n);
    }

    public bool Search (int x) {
        int position = 1;
        Node p = start;
        while (p != null) {
            if (p.info == x)
                break;
            position++;
            p = p.link;
        }
        if (p == null) {
            Console.WriteLine (x + "not found in list because use an idiot");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine (x + "is at position " + position);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int choice, data;

SingleLinkedList list = new SingleLinkedList ();

Console.WriteLine ("1.Display List");
Console.WriteLine ("2.Count Nodes");
Console.WriteLine ("search for an integer");

Console.WriteLine ("Enter your choice master: ");
choice = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

switch (choice) {

case 1:
    list.DisplayList ();
    break;

case 2:
    list.CountNodes ();
    break;

case 3:
    Console.WriteLine ("Enter the element to be searched");
    data = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
    list.Search (data);
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

How do I implement the CreateList method in the SingleLinkedList class to add nodes to the list?

Answer (score 4):

The single-linked-list pattern maintains a pointer/reference to the first node, and each item contains a pointer/reference to the next node in the list.  Appending to the list means finding the null reference - whether that's the root reference or at the end of the chain - and filling it with a reference to the new node:

```
public void Append(Node value)
{
    // check if we are adding to an empty list
    if (start == null)
        start = value;
    else
    {
        // find the last valid node
        Node curr;
        for (curr = start; curr.link != null; curr = curr.link);
        // add the item
        curr.link = value;
    }
}
```

The downside to this is that the more items you have in your list the longer it takes to find the end to add the next one.  In other words, it's an O(N) operation, and when you're adding thousands of items at once that gets *really* important.  For anything up to a hundred items or so you probably won't notice it much, but try adding 100,000 items to that list.

Fortunately it's simple enough to reduce the Append operation on the list to O(1) simply by keeping track of the last item in the list - the tail.

```
public class SingleLinkedList
{
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    public void Append(Node value)
    {
        if (head == null)
            head = value;
        else
            tail.link = value;
        tail = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can add items to a million-item list at the same speed (give or take a few microseconds) as a list with nothing in it.  You just have to remember to update the `tail` when you're removing items from the list as well.

---

As for searching, etc. you can implement `IEnumerable` and use LINQ to do all the work.  Or add an `Items` property that does it for you:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Items
{
    get 
    {
        for (var next = head; next != null; next = next.link)
            yield return next.value;
    } 
}
```

Now you can test for an item existing in the list with the following:

```
if (list.Items.Any(i => i == somevalue))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void AddNodeToList(Node nodeToBeAdded)
    {
        Node temp = null;
        if (start == null)
        {
            start = nodeToBeAdded;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = start;
            while (temp.link != null)
            {
                temp = temp.link;
            }

            temp.link = nodeToBeAdded;
        }

        nodeToBeAdded.link = null;
    }


 public void CreateList(Node[] nodesToBeAdded)
    {
        foreach (Node item in nodesToBeAdded)
        {
            this.AddNodeToList(item);
        }
    }
```